# Why does GCC stuff the source filename into the elf object and how do I stop it?

Tags: gcc, elf

Why does GCC seem to always stuff the source filename into the elf object?

Secondly, how do I stop it at compile time?

When I want to build an out-of-tree kernel module, my build directory gets stuffed into the kernel object. I can't think of any reason (other than debug tracing) why gcc would always stick the source filename/filepath into the elf object.

Example:

```
/* test_this_is_a_dumb_string_that_gcc_keeps_adding.c */
int func(void)
{
    int a = 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Then to build:

```
arm-linux-gcc -c -o test.o test_this_is_a_dumb_string_that_gcc_keeps_adding.c
arm-linux-ld -r test.o -o test.ko
```

Then see the string in xxd:

```
xxd -g 1 test.ko
```

Comment: Isn't `strip file.o` sufficient for you?

Comment: Not sure how to inject a strip into the KBuild system, and once it's linked 'relocatable', I don't think you can strip it.

Comment: Why would you be worried about it?  Truth in advertising indicates that the source file name can legitimately be stored.  Maybe you should look at the ELF section that contains the information, and see if there's a way to eliminate that.  Or rename your file to the name you want to see in the object file — that resolves the problem.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler file name is in .symtab section, and you'd better NOT eliminate that

Comment: When building with gcc -S, it looks like the offending data is assigned in the assember with .file .... so if I can instruct gcc to stop setting .file or override it myself, that may be a solution.